# Changing tootip data on pie chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been trying to edit the pie chart on [this website](https://www.vipim.com.au/test-page/) using the config method:

- Change colours (working)
- Show legend (working)
- Click legend to activate chart section (working)
- Donut sizing (working)
- **Tooltip different data (not working)**
- Legend showing percentages (not working)

I can't, for the life of me, get the legend to show the percentages and I can't get the tooltip data to change.

Currently, the tooltip says, for example:

> Australian equities
> Percentage: **40%**

I need the tooltip to say:

> Australian equities: **40%**

Currently, the legend says, for example:

> Australian equities

I need the legend to say:

> **40%** Australian equities

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).on('load',function(){
    if( typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined' ){ wpDataChartsCallbacks = {}; }
    wpDataChartsCallbacks[1] = function(obj){
        obj.options.plotOptions = {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            pie: {
                colors: [
                    '#006769', 
                    '#00b8af', 
                    '#28c3e8', 
                    '#0ee4da', 
                    '#2a97a6'
                ],
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                     enabled: false
                },
                size: 340,
                innerSize: '50%',
                showInLegend: true,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: function () {
                            this.select();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.point.name + ': <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) +'%</b>';         
                }
            },
            legend: {
                labelFormatter: function() {
                    return '<strong style="display:inline-block;width:45px;">'+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) +'%</strong> ' + this.name ;
                }, 
                title: {
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '18px',
                        fontFamily: "'neuzeit-grotesk', sans-serif",
                        color: '#20242b'
                    },
                    text : 'By industry'
                },
                squareSymbol: true, 
            },
        };
    };
});
</script>
```

This chart is feeding from a locally stored excel spreadsheet to reflect live data which is why the config method must be used.

I have read other threads and the highcharts forums but when I copy the codes into the above it still doesn't change the legend and tooltop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `legend` and `tooltip` configuration on the highest level:

```
{
    ...,
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            ...
        }
    },
    legend: {
        labelFormatter: function() {
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9sp4m1cf/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter

Comment: This does not work in the code I provided as I am not using the `Highcharts.chart('container', {` method. This chart feeds from an excel spreadsheet so I have to use the `wpDataChartsCallbacks` method. How would I do it using the latter?

Comment: is it because of the `obj.options.plotOptions` declaration at the start?

Comment: Hi @JaxJames, I don't know the `wpDataCharts`, do you have any API for it? The solution shows how it works in standard Highcharts.

Comment: Since this chart is feeding from an excel spreadsheet, I have to use the shortcode method in WordPress. I'm basing the above code from [this documentation](https://wpdatatables.com/faqmd/remove-datalabels-add-legend-pie-charthighcharts/)

Comment: Could you try store the tooltip and legend options in `obj.options`, not in `obj.options.plotOptions`?

Comment: Nope, that breaks the whole thing

Comment: According to the description: `You can use it for adding options that are available in Highcharts API.` - it should work. Sorry, I don't know `wpDataTables` well.